# Google Pixel not detected by adb on Fedora 27

Tags: android, adb, fedora

I am trying to connect my Google Pixel to my Fedora 27 with `adb`. In the past, this all worked seemlessly, but somehow something got broken now. I got an error message that I didn't have correct permissions, but now it doesn't even see the device anymore:

```
[bart@localhost ~]$ adb devices
List of devices attached

(... nothing follows ... )
```

My `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` looks like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0da4", MODE="0666"
```

(I removed the `GROUP="plugdev"`, as the `plugdev` group doesn't exist in Fedora).

When connecting the Pixel, I see this in my `dmesg` output:

```
[ 1268.799413] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[ 1268.814476] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee7
[ 1268.814479] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1268.814481] usb 4-2: Product: Pixel
[ 1268.814482] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: Google
[ 1268.814483] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: FA6BF0300146
[ 1268.816458] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[ 1268.816934] usb 4-2: Enable of device-initiated U2 failed.
```

I looked around trying to find some info online, but couldn't find any real solution. Of course, developer options and USB debugging are enabled on the Pixel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it.

I remembered that the Pixel has to be connected as PTP for all this to work.

Comment: I have a OnePlus One, and I had the exact same issue. Turns out that I had been using the "Charging only" USB connection mode. Changed it to MTP and it did the trick.